# Pass custom URL scheme data from AppDelegate to ViewController in Xcode 14

Tags: swift, xcode, appdelegate, url-scheme

Custom URL scheme starts my app, this part works!
Now I need to pass custom URL scheme data from AppDelegate to ViewController
It always be a empty string, why?

in AppDelegate:

```
    var window: UIWindow?
    var mytr: String!
    
    func application(_ app: UIApplication,
                     open url: URL,
                     options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        mytr = "TheData" //just try a string first
        return true
    }
```

in ViewController

```
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.webView.uiDelegate = self
        
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate
        let mypath = appDelegate?.mytr //here mypath always be "" why?
```

Comment: Obviously `viewDidLoad` is always called before `open url`. Use a callback closure or post a notification.

Comment: How can I know open-url in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Use the debugger to log the current time to prove that `viewDidLoad` is reliably called first.

Comment: Is it possible to get open-url(e.g. myscheme://myparam) directly in viewDidLoad function instead of from delegate?

Comment: No, because the delegate method is always called in a class conforming to `UIApplicationDelegate`

Comment: Got solutions from sceneDelegate! 
Anyway, thank you! @vadian